# [Meta] Bootstrap mode?

Tags: meta

StackExchange now offers "bootstrap" mode, which relaxes reputation requirements for things like up-voting while you're building your community.  Have you considered it?

Answer (score 1):

It's an option intended for the initial opening stage of the site where only admins would have to ability to do common and moderation tasks like commenting and downvoting.

It could be a consideration, but we also have to think about the purpose for the site's reputation system and even the name "bootstrap".

Any others interested?

Comment: As long as nobody else gets more rep than me I'm okay with it ;-)

Comment: They won't.  See my account on fogbugz.stackexchange.com.  Maybe I'm just used to the unlimited power I have there, but I find the inability to comment or upvote uncomfortable. We're going to keep fogbugz.stackexchange.com in bootstrap until we start seeing behavior that makes us want to disable it. There are still safeguards, even in bootstrap, like link limitations and activity caps. Anyway, take it for what it's worth. I got up to 49 rep with little effort in one morning, but I know the system.

Comment: @Rich and now you're about to break 100

Answer (score 1):

We saw when that came out, and considered it briefly. It would have been wonderful when we first started the site, but it doesn't seem as necessary today. Granted, I have enough rep to do what I need to do. As a newer user, do you feel limited by the reputation limits and the lack of users with higher rep, or is the site working well for you?

If enough people feel that they need to be able to create new tags and whatnot, we could change it. As it is now, I'm still cleaning up some bad tagging :)

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed people seem to stop giving answers to questions that have gotten an accepted answer already.  Its too bad really, because in some accepted answers I see room for improvement.  Maybe its a combination of too few users, and the newness of the platform to people.

I remind all users of the following:

1. Answers can still get voted up over an accepted answer by the communitity (theres even a badge for it).
2. The person posing the question can be wrong with his/her choice of answer or at least not the best informed themselves.
3. Continuing to vote only strengthens a question or answer when people look for what they want to know.

I posted this here because it seems to make sense while we are in bootstrap mode.

Comment: You're right. Of course, the worst is when a new user comes on, asks a question, accepts the first so-so answer, and leaves. There's plenty of these and StackOverflow.com, though, and the system is good at burying the less helpful answers over time.

Comment: Interesting and thanks for the insight.  To the site mods, how fast are new users coming in here anyway???